# can i put this ram into my imac 21.5 mid 2010 corsair cmso8gx3m2a1333c

Tags: imac

After installing computer wont boot up, just beeps. Uninstalled and put original 2x2gb samsung back in and computer booted up just fine.. Reinstalled the corsair and still nothing but beeping. Tried installing on top slots then on bottom slots. Computer tech at best buy assured me it would be compatiable with my iMAC

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google suggests that memory is two 4 GB SO-DIMM sticks of 1333 MHz DDR3, which matches the specs given by [Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4255?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) and [EveryMac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i3-3.06-21-inch-aluminum-mid-2010-specs.html).

It's possible that you've just got a couple bad sticks of RAM. I'd suggest testing them one at a time, rotating through the slots. If possible, test in another machine as well.